# Xcode 7 beta command failed with exit code 6

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, ios9, beta

lately, I have been trying the new beta of Xcode and I must say it is awesome, but when tried to import an older project, the compiling has been failed with exit code 6.

[image]

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Do you have any compile errors?

Comment: Nope, only the error I mentioned above

Comment: Try clicking the "All messages" tab.